# How to downgrade Google search app in recovery?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, google, system-apps, 8.1-oreo

For some reason, I would like to downgrade the Google search app (com.google.android.quicksearchbox) to a older version, and upgrade later, on a MI 8 running Android Oreo.
But when /system is mounted in recovery, I couldn't find the Google app in /system/app, although other system apps are there.
I don't want to root the device, so how to?

Comment: Find the directory Velvet under /system/priv-app/.

Answer (score 1):

some applications are in deferent locations, `system/app` holds certain applications while `system/priv-app` holds other's... sometimes your phone provider also puts apps in `system/vendor/operator/APP_FOLDERS_BY_NAME`   and `custom/app/`

These locations change depending on device, but mostly stick to the same root directory's..

- `system/app`
- `system/priv-app`
- `system/vendor/`
- `custom/`

Just have a look around at the different sub folders, and i think it's inconveniently named something completely different, like Velvet.apk